# iOS: SwiftUI compatible with Storyboards

Tags: xcode, swiftui, storyboard

Can we develop an iOS application with both storyboards and SwiftUI. is there anything like bridging available like we do bridging codes from objective c to swift and vice versa.

Comment: I’m sure you can find some WWDC19 videos on it. I remember them talking about how to incorporate SwiftUI with current projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface Builder supports adding a `UIHostingController` to a storyboard, which is the UIKit controller that can have a SwiftUI subview, but there’s no integration beyond that. You’d have to write your own methods and classes to pass data and actions between them.